# Issue while debugging Linux based C++ code visual studio code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my code in **visual studio code** in Linux - Ubuntu. I have configured the debugging configurations according to the specification. But when trying to debug I am getting the following error.

> =thread-group-added,id="i1" GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1 Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show
>   copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as
>   "x86_64-linux-gnu". Type "show configuration" for configuration
>   details. For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/. Find the GDB manual and other
>   documentation resources online at:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/. For help, type
>   "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
>   =cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off" Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed) Loaded
>   '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded. [Inferior 1 (process
>   18634) exited with code 0177] The program
>   '/home/source/src/.libs/main' has exited with code 177 (0x000000b1).

```
   launch.json

        {
            // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
            // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
            // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
            "version": "0.2.0",
            "configurations": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "C++ Launch",
                    "type": "cppdbg",
                    "request": "launch",
                    "targetArchitecture": "x64",
                    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/.libs/main",
                    "args": [],
                    "stopAtEntry": false,
                    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "environment": [],
                    "externalConsole": true,
                    "linux": {
                        "MIMode": "gdb"
                    },
                    "osx": {
                        "MIMode": "lldb"
                    },
                    "windows": {
                        "MIMode": "gdb"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
```

Comment: The salient part of your error is `Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed) Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded. [Inferior 1 (process 18634) exited with code 0177] The program '/home/source/src/.libs/main' has exited with code 177 (0x000000b1).` Where it appears you are attempting to load and compile/run in `gdb` a Linux *shared-object* library under a VS compile. I don't know how that would work under WSL, but you cannot expect VS (at least the versions I've worked with) to use a `.so` instead of a windows `.dll`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm facing the same problem, As you said VS cant use `.so` files. this mean I can't debug a program that uses `.so` files under VS, am I right?

Comment: @HMD You have options. WSL (whichever distro you choose) will provide `gcc`, so you can build your code with `gcc` (using the `-g` option to generate the `gdb` symbol file) Then you can debug with `gdb`.

Answer (score 4):

Because not all libraries (.a, .so) are linked to you project. I had the same problem. gdb outputs this error when it encounters a library call to a library that is not linked.

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled your program without debugging information. Compile it with `-g` compiler and linker option.